# How do I return the value of a variable from within a Catch statement?

Tags: powershell

I need to test for three possible states of a remote computer: Online, No RPC Server, or No Response.  I use a try-catch block to catch a non-terminating condition when the remote is online but the RPC server is unavailable.  I understand why the following code doesn't return the status for No RPC Server but I do not know how I should proceed.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated

```
$Status = ""
$hostname = Read-host("Enter Computer Name")
if (test-connection $hostname -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue){
    $Status = "Online"
    Try {
        $x = gwmi -Class win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $hostname -ErrorAction Stop
        }
    Catch{
        $Status = "No RPC"
        Continue
    }
}
Else{
    $Status = "No Response"
}
$Status
```

Comment: Take out the Continue.

Comment: Try `$using:Status = "No RPC"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to do any other processing in the function there's no real reason to use the `$Status` variable at all.  Just do a `Return "No RPC"` inside your `Catch` block(I'd also do the same inside your `Else` for consistency but that's entirely up to your preference).

Comment: Thanks for the speedy solution.  I'm fairly new to all this and appreciate the help.

Comment: happy to help, as a general rule try to avoid setting a variable just to return it in the next step, it creates some odd syntax problems (like you saw here) and also wastes memory, which doesn't matter 99% of the time in powershell work but is a big deal the other 1%, or if you decide to move on to more traditional programming languages.